# Cannot assign value of type 'String.Type' to type 'String?' - Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to populate my tableView with data from within an array, However when I try to assign the text of the Cell to the items in the array I keep getting the error:

> Cannot assign value of type 'String.Type' to type 'String?

Here's my code as it stands, I've tried a few other ways but this one seems like it's the closest one.

```
class ContactViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

  var contact:[Contacts]=[]

  struct Contacts {
     let name = String.self;
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath)
        let contacts = contact[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = contacts.name //This is where I get the error
        return cell
   }
}
```

Comment: Define structure like this  struct Contacts {let name: String}

Comment: Unrelated but semantically you should name the struct `Contact` and the variable `contacts`. `var contact:[Contacts]=[]` and `let contacts = contact[indexPath.row]` is pretty confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write "=" you're assigning a value, so when writing

```
let name = String.self
```

you're assigning the type of String to name. If you want to declare the type of a variable you should use semi-colon;

```
struct Contact {
  var name: String
}
```

If you quickly wants to populate your array with data just for testing, you can write:

```
struct Contact {
    var name: String
}

class ContactViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

  var contacts = [
      Contact(name: "First Contact"),
      Contact(name: "Second Contact"),
      Contact(name: "Third Contact")
  ]

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath)
        let contact = contacts[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = contact.name //This is where I get the error
        return cell
   }
}
```

Comment: This fixed my issue! The problem was indeed in the way I was declaring my name string in the `struct` :)

Answer (score 0):

You're not showing how you populate the array of `Contacts`, but the struct isn't declared correctly.

Presumably you want a struct that contains a name as a string. That would be declared such as:-

```
struct Contacts
{
  let name : String
}
```

Or with `name` declared with `var` instead of `let` if it needs to be variable.